# How to receive a JavaScript variable (two-dimensional array) in Python

Tags: javascript, python

## What I want to do

By Python (ver 3.7.7), I read a local htm file using an IE browser(I have to use IE 11) and use JavaScript to generate a two-dimensional array variable (element's id and height in IE browser).
I want to receive this variable in Python but I cannot now. Using this varible, I will conduct some data analysis.

### Codes

This is a local htm file (sample.htm).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="contents">
            <p id="p1">test</p>
            <p id="p2">test<br>test<br>test</p>
        </section>
        <script src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code in the above htm file(script.js).

```js
var all_ids = document.querySelectorAll("[id]");
var id_height_list = [];

for (var cnt = 0; cnt < all_ids.length; cnt++){
    var temp_list = [];
    var temp_id = all_ids[cnt].id;
    var temp_size = all_ids[cnt].getBoundingClientRect();

    temp_list.push(temp_id);
    temp_list.push(temp_size.height);

    id_height_list.push(temp_list)
}
```

Now, I use the below Python code to open the htm file by IE 11.

```py
import webbrowser
url = "path\to\sample.htm"

browser = webbrowser.get("path\to\iexplore.exe")
browser.open(url)
```

*id_height_list* in JavaScript is the variable I want to receive in Python.
Futhermore, because I have more than 10,000 htm files which I apply this code to, no manual intervention (e.g. click to save the variable) is favorable.

If you have ideas to receive this JavaScript variable in Python, please advise me.
Thank you.

Comment: you should look into Beautifulsoup, which is a python package. If you have a large number of files, the javascript that you are describing is of little value. Instead, Beautifulsoup can let you parse the files one by one and extract the data you need.

Comment: Thanks joelhoro. Yes, I know Beautifulsoup. However, in my case, I think Beautifulsoup is not suitable because I need actual IE 11 display size information of each element which is captured by getBoundingClientRect. The alternative solution is using Selenium. But its movement is a little heavy.

Comment: And 1 html file generates 1 observation of my final sample (including more than 10000 observations).

Comment: @YTKSKTKNM is this solved? Can you not use selenium headless?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Not yet. Although I can use Selenium to solve this problem, the Selenium method takes about ten seconds per html file (Therefore, it takes more than one day (ten seconds * 10000files) to finish this task). I think the above javascript method may be a faster one. Moreover, I think IE 11 webdriver does not have a headless option.